# How can I copy all pdfs from folders and sub folders?

Tags: command-line, mv

I need to move all my pdf files from one folder to another folder. How can I do this in terminal?

Answer (score 3):

To move all pdf's from a single folder to another folder:

`mv *.pdf /some/other/folder`

To move all pdf's from multiple folders to another folder

`find /home/user -name '*.pdf' -exec mv -t /some/other/folder {} +`

More information on find and mv can be found from man:

```
man find
man mv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use `mv`, use it with `find` and `xargs`. Read `man mv`. Read `man find`. Read `man xargs`.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 echo mv --target-directory=/somehwere/else/
```

Remove the `echo` when you're happy with the results.